# WordPress and SQL - Update and Insert from another table if column value doesn't exist

Tags: multisite, database, mysql

Stuck with some mysql for my wordpress site. All within 1 DB.

I am attempting to update `wp_options` table from `wp_2_options` (Multisite).

They both have `option_name` (unique_key) and `option_value` columns

It needs to update the `option_value` in the `wp_options` table if the `option_name` already exists in `wp_2_options` table

AND Insert the row from `wp_2_options` if the `option_name` doesnt exist.

So how do I `UPDATE` and `INSERT using the **UNIQUE KEY** value instead of the **PRIMARY KEY**

How do I do this?

Structure is the same for both of them

`wp_options (
  option_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  option_name varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  option_value longtext NOT NULL, 
  autoload varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes', 
  PRIMARY KEY (option_id), 
  UNIQUE KEY option_name (option_name) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1402 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE:

Ended up using this INSERT then UPDATE. This worked for me.
Will just use this through PHP now.

`-- Adding completely new rows from wp_2_options into wp_options
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_options
SELECT *
FROM wp_2_options
WHERE option_name NOT IN (SELECT option_name FROM wp_options);`

`-- Updating the option_name field in wp_options, if that got changed in wp_2_options
UPDATE wp_options JOIN wp_2_options
ON wp_options.option_name = wp_2_options.option_name
SET wp_options.option_value = wp_2_options.option_value;`

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP and the WordPress API. Place the following in `copy-options.php` and FTP it to `wp-content/plugins`, then activate it from the main site:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Copy Options
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/186092/1685
 * Description: Copy options from site 2 to site 1.
 * Version:     0.1
 * Author:      TheDeadMedic
 * Author URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic
 */

function wpse_186092_copy_options() {
    if ( 2 !== $blog_id = get_current_blog_id() )
        switch_to_blog( 2 );

    // Get all options from blog 2
    $options = wp_load_alloptions();

    // Switch to main blog
    switch_to_blog( 1 );

    foreach ( $options as $name => $value )
        update_option( $name, $value ); // Will update option if exists, insert if not

    // Switch back to current blog
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );     
}

register_activation_hook( __file__, 'wpse_186092_copy_options' );
```

Backup first. This code is not tested and comes without warranty.

Comment: Nice! Very handy. 

Unfortunately I don't have access to WP functions at this point only the database. 

Working on a deployment solution